# Activity design is breaking while opening input keyboard in Xamarin Android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I just start learning Xamarin android and facing some difficulties with LinearLayout and EditText control.
My activity design is totally braking when i click the text box and open the input keyboard.

Here is the screenshots.......

[image]
[image]

I have added this line of code in AndroidManifest.xml file but didn't get any positive output.

```
  <activity 
      android:name="CuttingQualityControlScanActivity" 
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"/>
```

Here is my xml design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
>    
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSite"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".09"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSite"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:text="Site"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"            
        />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnSite"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".60"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner"
            android:fadingEdge="none|vertical|horizontal"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTableNo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".09"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSite"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:text="Table No"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"            
        />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnTableNo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".60"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner"
            android:fadingEdge="none|vertical|horizontal"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llCuttingControl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".09"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"            
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >  

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtCutNo"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".35"
                    android:text="Cut No"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spnCutNo"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".55"
                    android:fadingEdge="none|vertical|horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner"
                    />       
            </LinearLayout>   


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtCuttingStatus"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".35"
                android:text="Cuttring Status"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spnCuttingStatus"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".55"
                    android:fadingEdge="none|vertical|horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner"           
                 />     
        </LinearLayout>  
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".09"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnbatchscan"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/ellipsshape"            
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llBadGoodControl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".09"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"            
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >  

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtGoodPanel"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".35"
                    android:text="Good Panel"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    />

                   <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            </LinearLayout>   


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/llBadPanel"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtBadPanel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".35"
                android:text="Bad Panel"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                />

                 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    
        </LinearLayout>  
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".09"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">
            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llPlyNo"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"            
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >  

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtPlyNo"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".35"
                    android:text="Ply No"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    />

                  <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>   


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/llPanelType"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtCuttingStatus"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".35"
                android:text="Panel Type"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spnPanelType"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".55"
                    android:fadingEdge="none|vertical|horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner"           
                 />     
        </LinearLayout>  
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llDefect"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".09"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDefect"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:text="Defect"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"            
        />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnDefect"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".60"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner"
            android:fadingEdge="none|vertical|horizontal"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llgoodbadgmt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".08"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        >

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnbadgmtqc"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Remove(-)"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbuttonbadgmt"

        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btngoodgmtqc"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Good GMT(+)"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbuttongoodgmt"

        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llsfdg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >
        <Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.SfDataGrid
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/sfDataGridQualitydata"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found a hints from Xamarin community and fortunately itsworked. All i need to add this line in oncreate method.

```
this.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustPan);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use RelativeLayout to design your UI, RelativeLayout are the layouts that span thru all available space and are then resized when the keyboard pops up.
And LinearLayout are layouts that don't get resized in the resizing process.

This is my simple sample that can Resize layout when soft keyboard appear.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Type here:"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/entry"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_below="@id/label"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/entry"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:text="OK" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ok"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/ok"
    android:text="Cancel" />
```

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Please don't forget add WindowSoftInputMode =Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize like this:

```
 [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true,  WindowSoftInputMode =Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize)]
```

If there are many controls in your RelativeLayout, you need to use ScrollView to contains RetativeLayout.

Comment: Thanks cherry for your answer.I have already found a solution.i just needed to use this line of code in OnCreate Method.

this.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustPan);